# Excel: suppress if cell above has the same value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible in Excel to suppress values in a column when the cell above has the same value?

I want something like this :

```
A            1234
             2345
             3456
B            4567
C            5678
             6789
D            7890
             8901
```

where the 2 cells under A are actually A, but hidden.

Ideally I'd want this in some sort of formula, because the data comes from a mysql merge and it has to do this automatically...

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicates as explained [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/excel-2010-remove-delete-duplicate-rows/)?

Comment: Generally people just want the opposite: you do realise that, by removing those "duplicates", you won't be able to filter on that column anymore?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This can be achieved with conditional formatting.

Assuming the data you want to hide is in Column A, for cell `A2` set Conditional Formatting formula to `=A2=A1` and format to `Number, Custom, ;;;`  then copy format down the column

Comment: For anyone wondering how `;;;` works: A number format can consist of up to 4 different parts separated by `;`, which are used to format positive, negative, zero and text differently. So `;;;` is a number format where each of those parts is formatted as 'empty', thus always resulting in an empty string

Comment: Format ;;; is excellent for number.  How about text?  My solution is conditional formatting to white font color.  But, you will see white text, if cell has filled color.

Comment: @yellowlarry If tested it you'd see it works for text too.  That's the blank 4th field (after the last `;`)

Comment: @Chris Yes, it works perfectly.  Thank you so much.