# Keep first row but delete duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need help in resolving below issue. 
I've an excel file with huge data, a sample data given below.

```
Name    RollNum      Subject    Marks
ABC       1          X          90
ABC       1          Y          56
ABC       1          Z          78
DEF       2          X          60
DEF       2          Y          78
DEF       2          Z          79
```

I want as below:

```
Name    RollNum     Subject  Marks
ABC        1          X      90
                      Y      56
                      Z      78
DEF        2          X      60
                      Y      78
                      Z      79
```

Comment: [Okay](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried?  Do you need to actually remove the data in columns A and B? What if you just make the text white (or whatever color) to simply make it not visible?  IMO, you're *much* better off keeping that data, so you can run reports/lookups/PivotTables and removing that data will make doing this much more tricky.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As you can see, someone already edited your question to raise the quality. You have to do the rest.

Comment: If you just want to hide the duplicates check the answer of chris neilsen [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173839/excel-suppress-if-cell-above-has-the-same-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to insert two new columns, one after `Name` and one after `RollNum`. Then enter the following formula into the cell B2 (assuming the spreadsheet starts at A1 `=IF(A2=A1, "", A2)` and the same into cell D2, replacing the As with Cs. Fill the formula for the entire column as needed, paste as values and then either delete or hide columns A and C as needed.

Comment: This is good idea, but I've more than 15 columns in my actual data. So I've to add 15 new columns and do the same. Any other simple solution required.

Comment: @UmakanthMadicharla - Does this answer work for what you wanted? (Just not clear, since it's marked as the answer, but your comment makes me think you're looking for something else?) Also, see my comment under your OP.

Comment: I think it works, but given the number of columns needed it isn't optimal. There's probably a better way using VBA.

Answer (score 4):

My *Duplicate Master* addin available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641067/brettdj?tab=profile) will let you delete the duplicates rows based on column A:B.

The addin also caters for case insenstive, white space, and/or regexp replacements

It will though delete the entire duplicate row.

So you would

1. Copy columns C:D to another sheet
2. Run the addin
3. Copy back in columns C:D to the updated sheet

`with settings`

[image]

`output`
[image]