# How To Get One To Many Relation In SQL Query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

How to do One To Many relation in SQL?? I have a query which print the output given : https://www.screencast.com/t/II0h2YXRi. Now I done Want To print the column Name which has the same Value.How Can I do IT?

```
DECLARE @agv NVARCHAR(max);

DECLARE @Con NVARCHAR(max);

SET @agv = '';

SET @Con = '';

SELECT DISTINCT dbo.bsContract.ContractNumber,Advertiser.OrganizationName AS Advertiser,
       JobName AS Campaign,bsContract.FromDate AS StartDate,
       Advertiser.OrganizationName AS Client,
      (ISNULL(cli.FirstName, '') + ' '  + cli.LastName) AS ClientRep,
       c.OrganizationName AS Vendor,
      (ISNULL(con.FirstName, '') + ' '  + con.LastName) AS 'VendorRep' 

FROM dbo.bsDocument

INNER JOIN Opportunity ON bsDocument.OpportunityID = Opportunity.OpportunityID

INNER JOIN Organization AS Advertiser ON Advertiser.OrganizationID = Opportunity.OrganizationID

INNER JOIN Contact AS UploadContact ON UploadContact.ContactID = bsDocument.UploadedBy

LEFT JOIN Organization ON bsDocument.OrganizationID = Organization.OrganizationID

LEFT JOIN dbo.bsContractLineItemV2 ON bsContractLineItemV2.ContractNumber = bsDocument.ModuleID 
          AND bsContractLineItemV2.VendorOrgID = bsDocument.OrganizationID 

LEFT JOIN dbo.bsContract ON bsContract.ContractNumber = bsDocument.ModuleID

LEFT JOIN Contact AS CompanyDocContact ON CompanyDocContact.ContactID = bsContractLineItemV2.VendorContactID

INNER JOIN dbo.Organization AS c ON c.OrganizationID = dbo.bsContractLineItemV2.VendorOrgID

LEFT JOIN dbo.Contact AS con ON VendorContactID = con.ContactID

LEFT JOIN dbo.Contact AS cli ON bsContract.ContactID = cli.ContactID

WHERE  MONTH(bsContract.FromDate) = 3 AND YEAR(bsContract.FromDate) = 2019 
       AND Advertiser.OrganizationName LIKE '%'+@agv+'%' 
       AND bsContract.ContractNumber LIKE '%'+@Con+'%'
```

Expected Output is https://www.screencast.com/t/mWifhgIb

Comment: This looks like sql server code - is the question tagged correctly or are you trying to convert to mysql?

Comment: Yes this SQL server code. How can I get the output of query  as shown above???

Comment: Are you saying you want some blank rows? This is usually done in a reporting tool, not a SQL statement. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Yeah you are write I needed this for reporting while transforming it to the excel

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you can, or should, do in SQL.  If you have code that processes the query result set and outputs it to file, you can do it in there.  Or, after exporting to Excel, you can apply conditional formatting to achieve the look, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9174254/3250365.